# Connect existing Drupal page with PhoneGap iOS App

Tags: iphone, ios, drupal, cordova

**Case:**
I have an existing page based on Drupal and going to develop a phoneGap iOS App. That means I just need the information of the existing page and want to fill these data in the new app.

**My Question** is now, do somebody know weather there is a work around or work flow to do so resp. how can I connect the existing page with another page or in my case phoneGap to get just the data? *I'm new with Drupal and phoneGap* so maybe you have some pages with information, tutorials or some help how to do this.

Thanks in advance *yves*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal offers a module called "Services" which will allow you to get data or services from your website. You may need to create your own methods on that module to get the information you want to retrieve.

As for the iOS side, you can retrieve the data via XML-RPC, Rest or whatever communication protocol you choose at the server side, or go all the way with drupal-ios.

https://github.com/workhabitinc/drupal-ios-sdk/

You should start looking for the Services module and play with it. You will have an embedded console on that module to test the methods.

Once you're finish with that, take a look at drupal-ios or go deep with your own implementation via XML-RPC or whatever.

Comment: It seems exactly the right way but could you help me to locate "Services"?  
I can't find where to activate this module.

Comment: You need to download it from http://drupal.org/project/services/ , extract it under the modules folder inside your Drupal folder, and activate it under Drupal Administration area

Comment: Thanks for your help @Yorxxx I'm now pretty far but standing almost still since days.

Comment: I setted everything up and got the REST Server working but I can't get the json file out of drupal.
That means by using an XMLHttpRequest like suggested in this tutorial [tylerfrankenstein.com/](http://bit.ly/um1dg4) I get problems with cross-domain requests. I also tried this beautyful piece of php code - [drupalRest](https://github.com/RandallKent/DrupalREST.PHP).  
Do you have any other suggestion how to get the data out of my existing page?